# When a 'v' letter should be changed to 'w' in botanical nomenclature?

Tags: botany, taxonomy, nomenclature

When should be 'v' changed to 'w' in botanical names? (especially ones derived from names originally written in cyrillics).

The International Code of Nomenclature for algae, fungi, and plants says that

> The letters w and y, foreign to classical Latin, and k, rare in that
>   language, are permissible in scientific names
>
> When the original publication of a name adopted a use of the letters
>   u, v or i, j in any way incompatible with modern nomenclatural
>   practices, those letters are to be transcribed in conformity with
>   modern nomenclatural usage.

Where should I look for the rules on such usage?